# Node Mongodb crash on Heroku while writing to DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, bson

I have a pretty straight code that writes one field to a hosted MongoDB, using the standard mongodb module. The application itself is running on Heroku and was working well for almost a year, when I started getting errors on the client side.

I added some console logs, and found 2 errors, coming from my db module:

1.

```
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
    throw err;
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:14:14)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
```

2.

```
Error: Cannot find module './collection/shared'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)

module.js:340
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
          ^
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    Process exited with status 8
    State changed from up to crashed
```

I cannot replicate those errors on my Mac - everything seems to work fine (accessing the same DB as the one on Heroku). I tried rolling back to mongodb v1.2 - no help, same errors.

Couldn't find anything on the googles or mongodb's JIRA, so I'd appreciate any help. For now, I surrounded the entire call with a try-catch, so it doesn't crash (but still doesn't work).

**Update**:
The try-catch doesn't help - I get the result once, but the app is marked as 'crashed' on Heroku, so I have to restart it manually. Will avoid DB call until issue resolved.

Comment: Are you sure all of the npm packages are installed correctly (and are the right versions?) You mentioned you'd rolled back to MongoDB 1.2? The current version is 2.4...?

Comment: I only use the mongodb module (not the DB itself), and it's currently at v1.3.2 (https://npmjs.org/package/mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an [issue on MongoDB's JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-104), and following a comment, I reset my app on Heroku. With Node v0.10.23, the problem never repeated itself. I still don't know what was the root cause, but I guess all is well now.

Comment: The last comment from the Node.js driver author in Jira was: "Happened due to a broken node.js 0.10.22 release".

Comment: I specified 0.10.23 in my original issue - not '22. Must be a typo. At any rate, water under the bridge :)

Comment: Hrm .. so not perhaps not actually a Node 0.10.22 bug. Thought would add the presumed resolution but seems like it was "turn it off and on again" (aka reset app on Heroku) ;-)